# Shopify REST API Authorization Credentials won't work

Tags: rest, request, authorization, shopify, shopify-api

i'm pretty desperate right now. I'm trying to send GET request to my `shopify` shop and the authorization (Basic Auth) of the request is not working:

```
("errors": "[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)").
```

I just don't get it, which username and password do i have to use? Are the App Credentials (`API key`, `API secret key`) not right? If not, what's the right password and how do i get it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your request URL ? How are you adding authorization to your request ? Share some code.

Comment: I'm writing from my phone so i can't post the exact details right now, but GET requests in my browser are working fine (chrome takes the cookie from my shopify login for authorization), which means the syntax of the request is correct. The only problem is, i don't get which username and password i have to use when i'm working with Postman (where i'm adding the authorization details in the corresponding UI).

Comment: Create a [Private app](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps#enable-private-app-development-from-the-shopify-admin), this will give you Access Token and Password. Those need to be used with Basic Auth in Postman.

Comment: I already have an app and i'm using the API key and API secret key, which i found in the app setup (the app itself is also using them successfully).

Comment: Then add those in [Basic Auth](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#basic-auth) in Postman.

Comment: I did but i keep getting the error

Comment: Ah sorry i have a public app, does it need to be a private app?

Comment: Private apps can use Basic Auth. For public apps, use [OAuth](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-a-public-app-with-oauth)